# jQuery function to override system default browser and my own?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, browser, outlook

I have a C# project, which has created an Outlook 2010 plugin. On click of the plugin a web based form loads inside the Outlook. The project loads form using the system default browser. I checked the project code and saw that `jQuery.browser` method is used to detect the system default browser specifics, and then use it in the program.

Now, I want to make a change to this code. All I want is to render the form using a browser of my choice, and not the system default one. Is there any jQuery function to override the default browser and use a custom one?

I am new to jQuery, and till now the online search I did, and articles I read, I didn't find any such method.

Your help help is appreciated!

Comment: UM, outlook picks the rendering engine (aka browser), you can not choose the browser with JavaScript.

Comment: The plugin most likely requests to open an URL (.url file type) and your operating system responds by opening the default browser (or the program associated with the .url file extension). JavaScript cannot interact with the system.

Comment: Is there anyway in my code (C# if not Javascript) I can set the browser to use, overriding the default selection?

Comment: what difference does it make?

Comment: It does. Actually, the same web form, when I am opening directly on some non-IE browsers, it is performing much more efficiently. It seems, the scripts are not efficient on IE. Hence, we need different browser rendering inside Outlook.

Comment: You can run a cmd command to open we page and also select the program. But unless the program has a path variable set in the system you have to get the path to the exe file

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand what you mean by using commadn to open web page. Can you please explain again? My constraint is, I need to open this page in Outlook form only, and not outside.

Comment: If I were you, I would put my efforts into making the scripts work better with IE since this is the ONLY browser you need to support with this addin.

Comment: The interesting thing is, this same code when I am running directly in IE, performance is good. But, the same thing when getting loaded inside Outlook form, it is taking a long time to load, and the button click functions also taking time. Hence, it looks like some issue with browser rendering inside Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Since the browser is the one running jQuery, jQuery cannot decide which browser runs it. Also, it is unaware of the context in which it's running, which is inside outlook.

To change this behavior you need to control it through outlook, though I highly doubt ms made chrome/ff available inside outlook.

Comment: Is there any hack or any programming I can do to change the browser  to a non-IE browser inside Outlook?

Comment: I don't know, I suggest you open a question especially for that goal.